# WCF PerCall Shared Resource Lock Issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, synchronization, locking

I am writing a service that will be hit constantly and from different sources. The service needs to persist data during some of the calls to a single shared resource. In this case an XML file (I know this is a stupid choice to store the data but I have no control over that decision).

So I would like the service to run in

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

since other than this case I have no need for sessions and there is very little set up code in my object constructors. However, static variables are not shared amongst each call of the service (which are coming in fast and furious). So a static lock on the file doesn’t work. I learned this the hard way:

```
private string _dataFile;

private static object _lock = new object();

private MusicData Get(string fileName)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MusicData));
            return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as MusicData;
        }
    }
}

private void Put(string fileName, MusicData data)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MusicData));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            x.Serialize(writer, data);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best strategy in this spot? I don’t want to change my `InstanceContextMode` to `PerSession` just for this and any sort of database solution is out of the question. The above code leads to the dreaded error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Comment: So maybe use `InstanceContextMode.Single` instead? Also `ConcurrencyMode.Single`. This will switch service instance to the singleton mode, i.e. a queue to process incoming requests turn by turn. You don't need even a lock then.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but my service needs to scale and will have a lot of requests coming in so queuing each request is not ideal. I would prefer to just queue access to the file and have all other operations run in parallel.

Comment: Hey @Eli the _lock is not referenced anywhere else. I wrote an integration test that uses: Parallel.For(0, 1000, MyFunc); Inside MyFunc I create a new instance of the service and write to the file.

Comment: How is your service hosted (IIS, self)? Its is clustered? I'm with @Eli Arbel in that it sounds like you have multiple AppDomains.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/06/17/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In the scenario you describe, shared client access to a single XML file, you may want to consider `InstanceContextMode.Single` coupled with `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`, providing that your service is stateless, thread-safe and re-entrant.

A WCF service using `InstanceContextMode.Single` coupled with `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` should not be responsible for any performance issues in your scenario.

The singleton service is the ultimate shareable service. When a service is configured as a singleton, all clients get connected to the same single well-known instance independently of each other, regardless of which endpoint of the service they connect to. The singleton service lives forever, and is only disposed of once the host shuts down. The singleton is created exactly once when the host is created.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

Comment: This would not address whatever reason there is he is observing multiple lock objects. WCF does not change the nature of static variables. Instancing mode has no say in this.

Comment: Interesting perspective. While my answer does not address the locking behavior issue, the answer seems to address the broader question of “What is the best strategy in this spot?” which I suggested he may want consider.  Seems reasonable and does not violate the condition of “don’t want to change my InstanceContextMode to PerSession”.

Comment: ConcurrencyMode.Multiple would not help him address the mutual exclusion he wants. InstanceContextMode.Single would not fix the lock. I don't see how he can solve his problem doing this.

Comment: Hey Guys. I will try Seymours suggestion and if it doesn't work I will post the full code so we can see if something else is going on here :)

Comment: Thanks Semour your suggestion worked. I would like to vote for it but it doesn't seem to be giving me the option :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, glad I was able to help. The following link might help with SO usage.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  Regards,